# How to send Json to Azure Appinsights with c# library

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm implementing the Azure's Application Insights and the API I found is I can only send there Dictionary of type `string` and `string`. Also if I use `TraceTelemetry` it has properties on it which again is dictionary of `string` and `string`.

However when I add one field to the custom properties (**cars** in my case) which has value of serialized json it will result in such a payload being sent to the Application Insights.

```
 "baseData": {
        "ver": 2,
        "message": "Test Message",
        "properties": {
            "cars": "[{\"Id\":0,\"Price\":{\"Value\":12.32,\"Currency\":.....
        }
    }
```

notice the backslash making it one json value.

But the appinsight portal will understand it - and parse it.

[image: Appinsight parsing string as json]

So I **can use** Microsoft provided C# API but it just looks ugly and seems like the API is JSON anyway, so why is API limited to `Dictionary<string, string>` ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct forum for such a question, since you're actually requesting for a new feature in the API, not for help with a specific issue. I suggest to post a suggestion in UserVoice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights

Comment: Perhaps you could open an issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues.

Answer (score -2):

It is because of filtering in Azure Portal. The main purpose of Properties (`Dictionary<string, string>`) is **provide the ability to find specified requests, exceptions etc**. You are also limited by count of properties (it was about 200). The typical properties are: "username", "isAuthenticated", "role", "score", "isAnonymous", "portalName", "group", "product" atc. Typically global properties.

If you want to send whole object / json, you can use `TrackTrace()`. You can find all the traces regarding to concrete request in portal.